# What are pressure threshold patches called in professional terminology?

Tags: pressure, terminology

I am making a small combustion chamber, and need to measure the pressure when a combustion occurs. This is a hobby project, so I don't have enough money to buy a dP cell with a remote membrane for temperature shielding. I recall there exist small patches (flat like paper) that change color when exposed to a pressure above a certain threshold.

Do you know what this is called in professional terminology?

(I have searched the internet for quite a while, but I can't seem to find it, let a lone anywhere to buy one.)

Answer (score 0):

Pressure-sensitive paints? Is that what you need? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-sensitive_paint

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand this correctly, the pressure-sensitive paint shows the pressure at the moment it is observed/measured. I was looking for something to put inside the combustion chamber, and looking at it after the combustion to figure out whether or not the pressure reached a given threshold.